# How does for act when it receives no commands?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I wrote a for-loop without any instructions(except for the ones within the for syntax). Now, when I use a semi-colon immediately after the ending for bracket, the i variable stops at the value 4, as expected; whereas if i do not use a semi-colon, it stops at value 6. How come?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++) //if the semicolon is absent here, value of x is 6
                      //if present, value of x is 4, as expected
    x=x+i;
    cout<<"x="<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a semicolon, your code is effectively the same as

```
int x = 0;
int i;
i = 4;
x = x + i; // x = 0 + 4;
```

since the `for` loop is equivalent to

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { } // sets i to 4
```

Without semicolon:

```
int x = 0;
int i;
i = 0; x = x + i; // x = 0 + 0;
i = 1; x = x + i; // x = 0 + 1;
i = 2; x = x + i; // x = 1 + 2;
i = 3; x = x + i; // x = 3 + 3;
```

being `for` loop equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { x = x + i; }
```

---

Read some good C++ book for beginners to learn more about the language syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This here

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
x=x+i;
```

Is actually the same as this:

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
    x=x+i;
}
```

The `for` always needs a statement after it, else it won't compile. To make it clear that the second line is the statement of the loop, it is often indented this way:

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
    x=x+i;
```

With the semicolon the code is equivalent to this:

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
    ; // does nothing, a so called "null statement"
}
x=x+i; // always happens once
```

Answer (score 1):

Without semicolon, your code is equivalent to

```
for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    x = x + i;
}
```

With semicolon, it is a one-liner and `x=x+i` is never called.

This is why in some code style guides, you are asked to always use brackets with for.

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote a for-loop without any instructions

No you didn't. It had one that you intended to be after the loop. A for loop *always* has a statement.

> Now, when I use a semi-colon immediately after the ending for bracket, the i variable stops at the value 4, as expected;

`;`, on it's own, is a statement. So is `{}`

> whereas if i do not use a semi-colon, it stops at value 6. How come?

Because it evaluates `x = x + i` as the loop body.

Unlike some other languages, whitespace does not delimit blocks. You can have *misleading* indentation. Applying an autoformatter would give you something like

```
int main()
{
    int x=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
        x=x+i;
    cout<<"x="<<x;
    return 0;
}
```